# 3 lights and 4 switches

Tags: wiring

I currently have a 3 gang box and a single gang box.

The single gang box operates the hall light(A)3 way.

The 3 gang box operates the hall light(A)3 way, the outside light(B)2 way, and the basement light(C)2 way.

We are having difficulty wiring new switches.
I think we have the single one ok, but when we put the new 3 way into the 3 gang box it doesn't work.  Please advise if possible with good diagrams.

Thank you

Peter

Comment: We probably cannot provide *good* diagrams without knowing how many circuit breakers are involved and where the power arrives at the circuits.

Comment: There is only one circuit breaker involved in all four switches and the power arrives at the far right of the 3 gang box.

Comment: Switch A on the right is 3 way for the hall light

Comment: Switch B is for the outside light and switch C is for the basement.

Comment: When you change the 3-way, how do you know which wires go to which terminals ? Position, screw color, or something else?

Comment: One more question -- does the cable to the hall light run from the single gang box or from the 3 gang box?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back on this thread.  We were able to figure it out on our own with some difficulty.  We went back to basics and pulled everything out.  We used our meter and checked for power and found it came into the light and through to the landing switch and on further to the bathroom.  So we hooked the switches together as per normal 3 way, but were confused as to what to do with the red wire in the box.  At first we just ignored it and the light worked as per normal, but quickly found we couldn't move forward to bring power to the other switches.

Comment: So we added the red wire back into the mix by joining it with the white wires to complete the circuit.  We then drew power from the white wires(which were from the black wires in the junction box for the light) for the other 2 switches.  Tested everything many times through out this process and were satisfied that everything worked as it should and put it back together.  Thanks again.